# Configure Symfony 3rd party bundle with container parameters declared in custom container extension / compiler pass

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony5, doctrine-dbal

I want to configure the *Doctrine bundle* to have a *DBAL* connection. For some reason the configuration needs a bit of logic to retrieve. I tried to use a [container extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html) and then a [compiler pass](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html) to execute the logic while the container is compiled and store the configuration as **container parameters**.

During my attempts, I registered the extension and compiler pass like this in the **Kernel** class:

```php
protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    // Those lines weren't there at the same time
    $container->registerExtension(new MyCustomExtension());
    $container->addCompilerPass(new MyCustomCompilerPass());
}
```

It seemed to work well as I could see my parameters in the console:

```sh
 # ./bin/console debug:container --parameters

Symfony Container Parameters
============================

 ------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
  Parameter                                                     Value                                                                   
 ------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
 ...
 some.prefix.host                                              some-mariadb-host
 some.prefix.dbname                                            some-database-name
 ...
```

The problem is that when I try to use those parameters in my `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` I get an error on my next console command:

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%some.prefix.host%'
        dbname: '%some.prefix.dbname%'
        # ...
```

```sh
# ./bin/console debug:container --parameters

In ParameterBag.php line 98:
                                                                                
  You have requested a non-existent parameter "some.prefix.host".
```

I am using **Symfony 5.3** and **Doctrine bundle 2.4**.

- Why do my parameters seem inaccessible for 3rd party bundle configuration ?
- How can I make this work ?
- Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Doctrine bundle configuration gets processed before my compiler pass can declare the parameters. It probably can't be solved using the DependencyInjection component.

Solved it by importing a PHP configuration file in the **services.yaml**:

```yaml
imports:
    - { resource: my_custom_file.php }
```

With the following content:

```php
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator\ContainerConfigurator;

return function(ContainerConfigurator $configurator) {
    // My specific logic

    // Saving the configuration as parameters
    $configurator->parameters()->set('some.prefix.host', $host);
    $configurator->parameters()->set('some.prefix.dbname', $dbname);
    // ...
};
```